# legend do not follow colors of series when it is set by series.columns.template.propertyFields.fill as when it is with series.fill

Tags: javascript, colors, legend

Legend does not follow colors of series when it is set by series.columns.template.propertyFields.fill as when it is with series.fill
The example is at 
https://jsfiddle.net/bosiljkakostic1/de16nbu7/4/
When you uncomment

```
//series1.fill = "red";
//series2.fill = "blue";
//series3.fill = "green";
```

example work well, but if color it is done by

```
series1.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color1";
series2.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color2";
series3.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color3";
```

legend color does not follow colors of series 
full code :

```
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<script>
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 * MODIFIED by Bosiljka Kosic, adding legend
 * and more series to describe the problem :
 * legend do not follow colors of series 
 * when it is set by  
 * series.columns.template.propertyFields.fill
 * as when it is with series.fill
 */

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "category": "Research & Development",
  "value1": 450,
  "color1": "red",
  "value2": 1200,
  "color2": "blue",
  "value3": 1500,
  "color3": "green"
},
{
  "category": "Marketing",
  "value1": 700,
  "color1": "red",
  "value2": 1000,
  "color2": "blue",
  "value3": 1200,
  "color3": "green"
},
{
  "category": "Distribution",
  "value1": 600,
  "color1": "red",
  "value2": 400,
  "color2": "blue",
  "value3": 1100,
  "color3": "green"
}              
             ];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "value1";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series1.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color1";
var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "value2";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series2.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "color2";
var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueY = "value3";
series3.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series3.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke= "color3";
series1.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "color1";
series2.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color2";
series3.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color3";
//series1.fill = "red";
//series2.fill = "blue";
//series3.fill = "green";
series1.name="2017";
series2.name="2018";
series3.name="2019";
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
</script>
<style>
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The legend markers grab the color from the fill of the series. When you comment that out your left with filling series' *columns* via property field binding. The `dataItem.dataContext` of legend markers are their associated series itself, so the columns' data are irrelevant, those never make it to the markers. Even if somehow the columns/their data were relevant, how would the chart know which of the columns to choose from to style the legend item?

What you can do is every time a column gets colored, update the legend marker for the column's series (or wait til a column is instantiated i.e. `columns.template.once("datavalidated", ...)` instead of an adapter, so it's only done once).

In order to [customize the legend markers](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Customizing_markers), we'll need to set `useDefaultMarker` to `true`.

```js
chart.legend.markers.template.useDefaultMarker = true;

chart.series.each(function(series) {
    series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
        chart.legend.markers.each(function(marker) {
            if (marker.dataItem.dataContext === target.dataItem.component) {
                marker.children.getIndex(0).fill = fill;
            }
        });
        return fill;
    });
});
```

Fork of your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/notacouch/ot5uadez/

Comment: You can check the series type like         if(series.className === "ColumnSeries")          else if (series.className === "LineSeries")       and change the check LineSeries event like this:          series.adapter.add("fill", function (fill, target)

Comment: @UmutBebek Ah I see. In that case you could instead swap out `series.columns.template` with a variable that is adjusted based on the condition you mentioned. I haven't tested any of this, but that's 1 possibility to leave the code flexible/abstract.